# How to plot a gaussian curve over histogram in chart.js?

Tags: histogram, gaussian

I create histogram with gaussian curve, but first data point of curve is skipped.

My example:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'horizontalBar',
data: {
    labels: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
            9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
    datasets: [{
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99,                               132,0.5)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [3,1,0,0,0,2,0
              ,2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    },{
      type: 'line',
      fill: false,
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [
{
"x": 0.4175611241375584,
"y": 0
},
{
...other points
}
],
      borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      radius: 2
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
           categoryPercentage : 1,
           barPercentage: 1
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'bottom',
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
            min: 0,
            max: 4
          }
        }]
    }
}
});
```

https://codepen.io/krna/pen/ejzqwg

When I only draw a Gaussian curve, all points are drawn correctly.

Inversion of histogram doesn't help.

I tried many strange tricks with data and chart axis configuration, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in 0 value on y-axis, it's probably interpreted as null instead of 0. You can make this work however, by making the labels and y values a string. Full answer You could find on https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5641.